# Confusion about using OpenEJB in embedded mode for unit-testing

Tags: unit-testing, ejb, jndi, openejb

I started exploring the possibilities of using OpenEJB in embedded mode for unit-testing my EJB3 components. At first I got errors like the below output

```
Testsuite: HelloBeanTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Time elapsed: 1,779 sec
------------- Standard Output ---------------
Apache OpenEJB 3.1.4    build: 20101112-03:32
http://openejb.apache.org/
------------- ---------------- ---------------
------------- Standard Error -----------------
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.apache.openejb.resource.activemq.ActiveMQResourceAdapter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
------------- ---------------- ---------------

Testcase: sum took 1,758 sec
Caused an ERROR
Name "HelloBeanLocal" not found.
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "HelloBeanLocal" not found.
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:193)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:150)
at 
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.ContextWrapper.lookup(ContextWrapper.java:115)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at HelloBeanTest.bootContainer(Unknown Source)

# ... output is the same for all the rest of the tests
```

The openejb.home property is set as a system property and points to my OpenEJB installation dir.

The *HelloBeanTest#bootContainer()* is a setUp method and it fails on the JNDI lookup. Shown below.

```
@Before
  public void bootContainer() throws Exception{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
             "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
    Context context = new InitialContext(props);
    hello = (Hello) context.lookup("HelloBeanLocal");

}
```

After struggling with problems like this I started to try out OpenEJB in non-embedded mode, and started the container from it's installation directory and deployed the components as an ejb.jar. Deployment was successful and I started creating a stand-alone Java client. The stand-alone Java client is still unfinished, but meanwhile I came back to testing in embedded mode.

To my surprise, the tests suddenly started to pass. I added some more functionality to the component and tests for those. Everything worked just fine. Below is the output for that run.

```
Testsuite: HelloBeanTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 2,281 sec
------------- Standard Output ---------------
Apache OpenEJB 3.1.4    build: 20101112-03:32
http://openejb.apache.org/
------------- ---------------- ---------------
------------- Standard Error -----------------
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
(org.apache.openejb.resource.activemq.ActiveMQResourceAdapter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
------------- ---------------- ---------------

Testcase: sum took 2,263 sec
Testcase: hello took 0,001 sec
Testcase: sum2 took 0 sec
Testcase: avg took 0,001 sec
```

I was happily coding and testing until it broke again. It seems that removing the ejb.jar from /apps directory caused it. So, it seems that OpenEJB does the JNDI lookup still from the installation dir, but uses the current dir to find the actual implementations when running in embedded mode. I made this conclusion as the ejb.jar deployed in apps/ dir does not have all the methods that the local version has. (I double checked with javap.) Only the class signature is the same.

After this very long introduction, it's question time.

- Can anyone provide any explanation for this behaviour?
- Packaging and deploying the EJBs in the apps/ dir before testing is simple task, but can I be sure that even then I am testing the correct implementation?
- Does this all have something to do with the openejb.home property pointing at the OpenEJB installation dir?

For summary, OpenEJB version is **Apache OpenEJB 3.1.4 build: 20101112-03:32**, which is visible in the log outputs as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have something to do with setting the `openejb.home` to point to the installation dir.

There's a `conf/openejb.xml` file that likely has a `apps/` listed as where deployments live.  All the log output went to the `logs/` dir and not in System.out of the test case where you can read it easily.

To use OpenEJB embedded you don't need any config files, directories, or ports.  You just include the libs in your project's classpath.

First thing I'd say is to check out the [openejb-examples-3.1.4.zip](http://openejb.apache.org/download.html).  There are maybe two dozen example projects all setup with both Ant and Maven build scripts.  All the examples will work in any environment as long as the OpenEJB libraries are in the classpath.  Here's a video of using one of the examples to [unit test in Eclipse](http://www.vimeo.com/6149008). I recommend the `simple-stateless` example as the best starting point.

Comment: OK I got it working, or so it seems. I made the configuration so that I set only openejb.configuration system property to point to a openejb.xml configuration file where I define where to look for the beans. Tests pass, output is given in the report and the openejb.home property points to my project dir.

Comment: Then again the documentation on [OpenEJB site says](http://openejb.apache.org/embedding-openejb.html) 

_"If you use OpenEJB Local Server, you are actually using OpenEJB as an embedded library. This means when your application starts, OpenEJB will be starting too, in your virtual machine. Odds are you will not want to execute your application in the directory where OpenEJB was installed, but will want to execute your application where you are developing it. This is fine, but you will need to tell OpenEJB where it was installed. To do this, set the "openejb.home" system variable."_

Confusing?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's an orphaned page and very outdated.  It now includes the content of [this page](http://openejb.apache.org/local-server.html).  Please try without any `openejb.configuration` or `openejb.home` setting at all.  It can work with those, but it won't be much fun.  Pointing to the config file which points to a directory pointing to apps is a little brittle.  File paths in tests can be problematic.  OpenEJB is capable of finding the apps using just the classpath itself and will create any containers needed with no config necessary.

Comment: Great! I got it working. After some investigation I found that the jar containing EJBs must have (empty) META-INF/ejb-jar.xml file inside when it is loaded from classpath. When the EJB jars are loaded via the configuration file's deployment dir, this is not necessary. OpenEJB documentation does mention this fact. Thanks for replies and comments. Keep up the good work with OpenEJB (and especially the embedded mode)!